# Flatten array in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get an array of a list of random ids from a model, I do:

```
User::all('id')->random(5)->flatten()->toArray()
```

But this still out a multi array:

```
0 => array:1 [
   "id" => 20
]
1 => array:1 [
   "id" => 69
]
....
```

Im looking for something like:

```
[20, 69]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck):

```
User::all('id')->random(5)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```