# Pluck not working as expected in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855538/flatten-array-in-laravel), I need to get an array of a list of random ids from a model, I do:

```
User::all('id')->random(2)->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

The above works as expected, plucking 2 ids and putting them in an array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => 63
  1 => 270
]
```

When I switch it to just one random user though:

```
User::all('id')->random(1)->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

The entire table is returned.

```
array:200 [
  0 => 63
  1 => 270
  2 => 190
  ...
]
```

My plan is to use the following to get between 1 and 10 users:

```
 User::all('id')->random(rand(1,10))->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

But how can I make this work when only 1 random user is selected, why is the entire table being returned?

Comment: Probably because getting only one user doesn't return a collection. It's just one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your database to randomize your users, and take full advantage of the query builder and its `take` method.

```
User::inRandomOrder()
    ->take(rand(1,10))
    ->pluck('id')
    ->toArray();
```

`inRandomOrder` was added in Laravel 5.2+, so if you have less, you can do `orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))` for MySQL (see this post to learn more [Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row))

Answer (score 1):

`random(1)` will not return a collection, while `random(2)` and above will.  You can first get the query and then handle the results differently dependent on whether or not the result was a collection.